# How do I communicate with an ATtiny85 development board that has V2.2 bootloader?

Tags: arduino, attiny85, development

I'm very new to this so go easy. I'm trying to download a program to an ATtiny85 development board with a microUSB connection. All the posts I've read keep referring to a much older IDE version. I eventually caved and installed said version (1.6.5r2 I think). I spent a heap of time setting it up as per the various posts, only to have an error message:

```
This tool doesn't know how to upload to this new device. Updates may be available.
> Device search timed out
Device reports version as: 2.2
```

I found some help at
 https://kovo-blog.blogspot.com/2019/01/how-to-upgrade-bootloader-on-digistump.htm 
 but the instruction

```
git clone git@github.com:micronucleus/micronucleus.git
```

caused an error.

```
daniel@pop-os:~$ git clone git@github.com:micronucleus/micronucleus.git
Cloning into 'micronucleus'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '13.236.229.21' to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
daniel@pop-os:~$
```

and that was that.

Help to get up and running with these micros would be well appreciated.

Comment: Daniel - Hi, I realise you are probably getting used to Stack Exchange. I just want to warn you that you have written a comment here, on the *question* which seems to really be a reply to an [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/492350). So saying thanks here makes no sense and will be confusing to readers. Writing it here also means that the person who wrote the answer will not get an automatic notification of your comment, so might not even see it! I recommend you re-write your comment below that answer (if that is what you intended) and delete it from here (below the question).

Answer (score 0):

The git clone is failing because you don't have the proper ssh credentials to clone that repo through ssh (which that url is trying to do). Try running:

`git clone https://github.com/micronucleus/micronucleus`

That will clone over https rather than ssh

Comment: Thanks, that worked well. Now it's getting hung-up on the next command `daniel@pop-os:~/tmp$ cd micronucleus/commandline/ ; make make: libusb-config: Command not found Building library: micronucleus_lib... gcc -Ilibrary -O -g -D LINUX -c library/micronucleus_lib.c In file included from library/micronucleus_lib.c:30: library/micronucleus_lib.h:35:10: fatal error: usb.h: No such file or directory #include <usb.h>` ARGH!